# How to do a motion without leaving history (in .)?

Tags: normal-mode, cursor-motions, repeated-commands, object-motions

Often, you do a complicated motion, which you want to repeat soon by pressing `.` but carry out a simpler motion overwrites that one. Can I keep that complicated motion in `.` itself ?

**Concrete example**:

Say the cursor is under `1` in the following

```
foo(b1ar,bar(f,f) )
```

I'll do `c])`followed by `a1<ESC>` to change it to
`foo(ba1)`.
And then I'll do a series of mundane motions quickly.
Now when I go to the next line, I want to again invoke `c])` `a1<ESC>` by pressing `.` instead of repeating my last motion.

PS Making a macro just for this seemed slight overkill.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: It's a great question... I think you can make a couple of clarifications though: *"I'm at '1' in the following"* There are actually two 1's... Maybe fix it to "the first '1'" or perhaps "the '1' in "b1ar"" or similar. You could also be more explicit that "The cursor is under..." (rather than just "I'm at..."). Second, after `c])` you're in Insert mode, and from the context I'm guessing you're inserting `a1`, is that correct? If so, please be more explicit and include that part of the command too. After all, that's part of what gets repeated, right?

Comment: Really glad to have this community!

Comment: For what it's worth, this is exactly the case I _do_ use a quick macro.

Comment: Yeah, generally speaking for ad hoc repeating of an operation a macro is the best answer (and probably the only practical one) here, IMO. I wouldn't call them "overkill". It requires just three extra key presses to set up and two to use (plus, maybe, a couple key presses for a count). You can keep it around for as long as you need or ditch it right away. You can save a whole bunch of them. Etc.

Comment: (cont) Actually, let me revise that. For really short command sequences especially if needed for a small number of repetitions, yeah, that's probably overkill. If I needed to repeat your example just one or two other times I'd do it manually. Otherwise, macro time. :)

Comment: Its so funny how we all think so alike. @BLayer, I completely agree with you, and was indeed proceeding precisely the way you mention! 
But two things, (1) I'm _really_ curious as to if this can be done in another way. 
(2) I don't like the context switch in my head that it entails. Sorry for being so finicky, but hey! that's what Word users think of us Vim users no?

Comment: There's no other general purpose, practical, native solution to this.